# I've created a new project in XCode with a specific letter("Ş") and these errors come with it. But I saw a lot of apps with specific letters

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[image: First of all, XCode change my project's name from "Şotka" to "S_otka" as you see. I thought it was done without errors. But isn't easy as I think.]

[image: These errors come when I build my project on the simulator. And appears black screen.]

What can I do to fix these errors without changing my project's name?

Comment: "But I saw a lot of apps with specific letters" You might be seeing the app's *display name*, which can be set in your project settings.

Comment: @Sweeper You are right, I didn't know that. Thanks.